# Ubuntu 14.04 running from usb stick is slow

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

I am using Ubuntu for the first time, I have tried it before, but I accidentally deleted all my partition, after that I installed it on my 16Gb pen drive, but now it is so slow it takes a lot of time on every click. What can I do about it?

Comment: Why don't you reinstall it to your hard drive? a usb stick will always be slow unless you're using usb 3.0

Answer (score 2):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

Try Lubuntu. Lubuntu uses light LXDE desktop.
Lubuntu is focus on speed and energy-efficiency with low hardware requirements.

http://lubuntu.net/

good luck